# The Hessian of a Radial Basis Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

In [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0307904X06002009) paper the Hessian of a RBF is shown as

$$
H_j = \frac{\beta_j}{r_j(x)} \bigg(
\phi'(r_j) I +
\bigg[
\phi''(r_j) - \frac{\phi'(r_j)}{r_j(x)} 
\bigg]
\bigg) (x-x_j) \frac{\partial r_j}{\partial x}
$$

where

$$
r_j = || x-x_j|| = \sqrt{(x-x_j) ^T (x-x_j)}
$$

and $\phi(r)$ could be one of the many RBF functions, such as $\phi(r) = \exp(-cr^2)$.

An RBF is of course

$$
f(x) = \beta^T g(x) = \sum_i \beta_i \phi(r_i)
$$

I understand how the Jacobian is obtained, but was not able to derive the Hessian. Where did the identity matrix come from? Why $H_j$ and not $H_{ij}$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the radial vectors  $\,w_k = (x - x_k)\in{\mathbb R}^n\,$ and note their differentials are identical $\,dw_k = dx$.

Concatenate the vectors into a single matrix
$$\eqalign{
\Omega&=\big[\,w_1\;w_2\;\ldots\;w_m\big]&\in&{\mathbb R}^{n\times m} \\
d\Omega&=\big[\,dx\;dx\;\ldots\;dx\big] &= &dx\,{\tt\large 1}^T 
}$$
Note that the $\,r_j=\|w_j\|\,$ are themselves elements of a vector 
$\,r\in{\mathbb R}^m$.

The cartesian base vectors $\,e_k\in{\mathbb R}^m$ allow us to write all of the above as
$$w_k=\Omega\,e_k,\quad dx=d\Omega\,e_k,\quad r_j=e_j^Tr$$
Applying the RBF function element-wise avoids summations and subscripts. Simply write the derivatives and differentials as
$$\eqalign{
&g=\phi(r),\quad g'=\phi'(r),\quad g''=\phi''(r)\;&\in{\mathbb R}^m \\
&dg=g'\odot dr,\quad dg'=g''\odot dr \;&\in{\mathbb R}^m \\
}$$
where $\odot$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product.

It will also be useful to switch between vectors and diagonal matrices, which will be indicated by an uppercase letter, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
&R={\rm Diag}(r),\quad &G={\rm Diag}(g),\quad &G''={\rm Diag}(g'')\;\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times m} \\
&r = {\rm diag}(R),\quad &g = {\rm diag}(G),\quad &g''=\ldots \\
&r  = R{\tt\large 1},\quad &g = G{\tt\large 1},\quad &g''=\ldots \\
&dg = G'dr,\quad &dg' = G''dr \\
}$$
and it will prove convenient to define
$$
P=R^{-1}\quad\implies PR=I,\;\;p\odot r = {\tt\large 1}
$$

Now write down the main relationship and differentiate it.
$$\eqalign{
r\odot r &= {\rm diag}(\Omega^T\Omega) \\
2r\odot dr &= {\rm diag}(\Omega^Td\Omega+d\Omega^T\Omega)
 \;=\; 2{\,\rm {diag}}(\Omega^Td\Omega) \\
R\,dr &= {\rm diag}(\Omega^Tdx\,{\tt\large 1}^T) \;=\; \Omega^Tdx \\
dr &= P\Omega^Tdx \\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} &= P\Omega^T \\
}$$
A quick check of the $i^{th}$ component recovers Eqn (18) from the paper and confirms that we're on the right path:
$$\eqalign{
e_i^T\bigg(&\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\bigg) = e_i^TP\Omega^T \\
&\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial x} 
 \;=\; \frac{1}{r_i}\;e_i^T\Omega^T
 \;=\; \frac{w_i^T}{\|w_i\|} \\
}$$
The model function (replacing $\beta$ with the easier to type $b$) is
$$f = b^Tg = b:g$$
where the colon is the Frobenius product notation for the trace, i.e.
$\;A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

Calculate the differential and gradient of the model.
$$\eqalign{
df &= b:dg \;=\; b:g'\odot dr \;=\; g'\odot b:dr \\
  &= (g'\odot b):P\,\Omega^Tdx \\
  &= \Omega P(g'\odot b):dx \\
  &= \Omega PG'B{\tt\large 1}:dx \\
J=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 &= \Omega PG'B{\tt\large 1} 
 \;=\; \bigg(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\bigg)^T\Big(b\odot g'\Big) \\
}$$
All that hard work produced the Jacobian (gradient). Now on to the Hessian.
$$\eqalign{
dJ
 &= d\Omega\,PG'B{\tt\large 1} + \Omega PdG'B{\tt\large 1} + \Omega\,dP\,G'B{\tt\large 1} 
\\ 
 &= dx\,{\tt\large 1}^TPG'B{\tt\large 1} + \Omega PB\,dg' - \Omega (P\,dR\,P)G'B{\tt\large 1}
\\
 &= dx\,({\tt\large 1}^TPG'B{\tt\large 1}) +\Omega PB\,dg' -\Omega PG'PB\,dr
\\
 &= (G':PB)\,dx +\Omega PBG''\,dr -\Omega PG'PB\,dr
\\
 &= \Big((G':PB)I +\Omega PB(G'' - PG')P\Omega^T\Big)\,dx
\\
H = \frac{\partial J}{\partial x}
 &= (G':PB)I + \Omega PB(G''-PG')P\Omega^T \\
 &= \Big((p\odot b):g'\Big)\,I \;+\; \bigg(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\bigg)^T\Big(BG''-BPG'\Big)\bigg(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\bigg) \\
}$$
Although it may not look like it, this result is identical to Eqn (21). The above form has the advantage that it is *obviously* symmetric (as it must be) whereas the result in the paper is awkward.

When manipulating the above expressions, keep in mind that the $(R,G,B)$ matrices are all diagonal and therefore commute with one another, however $\,\Omega\,$ is a full matrix and does not commute with the others.

The clumsy notation $H_j$ does not refer to a vector or matrix element, but rather to the fact that $H(x)$ was evaluated at the point $x=x_j$. All of the variables above, except for $(b,1,e_k,B,I)$, are implicitly functions of $x$. So you could slap a $j$ subscript on each of them to calculate the expression for $H_j$.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer. Oddly enough this is the first doc of its kind now talking abt RBF Hessian, so it comes out on top on Google searches!

Comment: I need to do some studying to grok Hadamard products, and the Frobenius notation.